# Executing a command and storing its output in a file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

In command prompt...

First execute Batch file
then execute numbers of commands.

so how can i store all that command and its output in a single file,
and file path define in batch file. ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i store all execute command and its output in a single file ?

Comment: Have no command `Echo off` inside the batch and invoke the batch with a redirection? Depending on the loops inside you'll get more output than expected.

Answer (score 0):

like this maybe

```
@echo OFF
(
Echo Ipconfig
Echo.
Ipconfig
Echo.
Echo.
Echo Net User Guest
Echo. 
Net user Guest
)>file.txt
Exit
```

Or you could set the commands as variables and then type it instead of the whole command.

Comment: And by the Way i did mention that it only World for one Line on text

Comment: no need for temp files: `>file.txt (`, `ipconfig`, `net user Guest`, `)`. But it still doesn't capture the commands, just their output.

Answer (score 0):

And easy Way to create a batch prompt that saves its output you could do it like This:

```
@echo off
:top
Cls
Set /p c=
Echo %c% >> output.txt & %c% >> output.txt
%c%
Echo. >> output.txt
```

Goto top
Of course then run the command and then create a space for the next Line